# Record and save a live video streaming in iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, rtsp, live-streaming

I am using dfurtsp player which is wrapper around ffmpeg player. I am able to play the live streaming successfully. Now I want to record the video as well. Please suggest me how to get started with the recording functionality.

I have also searched other players which supports recording but didn't find any. If anybody knows any other player which supports this please let me know.

Comment: This is either "too broad" or "request for third party resources" and as such is not an ideal fit for Stack Overflow.